# Combining user specific TensorFlow models into one, based on the userId

Tags: tensorflow, scaling, operations, serving

Seeking advice on how to approach a situation where we have to train the same simple model (not NNs) for each individual user and their *content* which must remain private - this means I would theoretically have 150k different models to deploy/operate in parallel (possibly a nightmare).

Is it possible in TensorFlow to train/freeze these individual models completely separately, and then load + combine them into one larger model for saving at deployment time (as no training is required) that takes a userId as an additional input.

If not, is there a typical approach to this problem?

Comment: What kind of "simple model" are you training? If it's very simple (e.g., linear regression or logistic regression), you might be better off with a more lightweight package such as sklearn, where training is faster, model size is smaller, and it is more feasible to load a large number of models to RAM simultaneously.

Comment: Some recommendation models (collaborative filtering) and classification tasks at this stage.

Comment: In the short term we’re considering that, but are also exploring other options like this. With regards to SKL and others, we suspect they will impose various other limitations specific to our use case and it becomes a trade off but thank you for the input! TensorFlow Serving appears to be fairly appropriate for us, but unfortunately at this stage that would appear to limit us to TF models without contributing to the library ourselves :-)